# Why are my li elements moving when I give them an inner border?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, navigation

I am using the following code to get a `hover` effect in my navigation: [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/hkh82ot6/)

When I hover the `li` elements they're moving. How can I avoid that?
I tried to give the `li` elements a white border, but the elements now aren't vertically centered anymore.

Comment: Use transparent border https://jsfiddle.net/hkh82ot6/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use transparent border in `li` tag.

```css
header img {
  width: 59px;
  height: 32px;
  float: left;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1em;
  height: 90px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top: 8px solid rgba(0, 0, 0,0);
}

nav li:not(:last-child) {
  margin: 0px 40px 0px 0px;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  border-color: rgb(109, 155, 166);
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(62, 74, 89);
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

header {
  max-width: 960px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 90px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <img src="images/logo.png" alt="BW">

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="google.de">Start</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">&Uuml;ber mich</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pakete</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding border in hover change the contents for the element so you should provide you css  whit transparent border  when not  hover

```
nav ul li {
   border-top:8px  solid transparent;
   display: inline-block;
   font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
   font-weight: 400;
   font-size: 1em;
   height: 90px;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that they are moving. First you have no border, so they are at the top and when you hover it, you have a 8px border, so they run 8px down.

The solution is easy. You have to add a transparent border to your li at the beginning.

```
nav ul li {
   border-top: 8px solid rgba(0, 0, 0,0);
}
```

or

```
nav ul li {
   border-top: 8px transparent;
}
```

Both Solutions are possible, but not every (old) browser accepts the transparent tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code...

```
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1em;
  height: 90px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li:hover::before {
  /* border-top: 8px solid rgb(109, 155, 166); */
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgb(109, 155, 166);
}
```